# How to display bitmap pixel by pixel in Android?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, pixel

I am trying to display a bitmap image pixel by pixel (which explicitly means with some delay).
For that I am using two "for-loops", but it prints only a single row of pixels...

My code:

```
Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Printing...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        iImageArray = new int[bMap.getWidth()* bMap.getHeight()];                                   //initializing the array for the image size
        bMap.getPixels(iImageArray, 0, bMap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight());   //copy pixel data from the Bitmap into the 'intArray' array  
             
        //Canvas canvas = new Canvas (bMap);
        //replace the red pixels with yellow ones  
        for (int i=0; i < bMap.getHeight(); i++) {  
            for(int j=0; j<bMap.getWidth(); j++) {
                iImageArray[j] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
            } 
        } 
        bMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(iImageArray, bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);//Initialize the bitmap, with the replaced color
        image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
        //canvas.drawPoints(iImageArray, 0, bMap.getHeight()*bMap.getWidth(), paint);
    }
});
```

And I want to print the bitmap in grayscale and for that I found this code...

```
public Bitmap toGrayscale(Bitmap bmpOriginal) {        
    int width, height;
    height = bmpOriginal.getHeight();
    width = bmpOriginal.getWidth();    

    Bitmap bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bmpGrayscale);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
    cm.setSaturation(0);

    ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
    paint.setColorFilter(f);

    c.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, paint);

    return bmpGrayscale;
}
```

It is `iImageArray[i] = 0xFFFFFFFF;` that I have to test, not the actual grayscale value...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks basically correct except for your inner loop. Your comment says that you're setting them to yellow, but you're actually storing white. The loop will only affect the first row of pixels because your array index has a range of 0 to width-1. You can either calculate the index by multiplying (i*width+j) or keep a counter that increments.

**Original Version:**

```
//replace the red pixels with yellow ones  
for (int i=0; i < bMap.getHeight(); i++)  
{  
    for(int j=0; j<bMap.getWidth(); j++)
    {
        iImageArray[j] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    } 
}
```

**Fixed Version:**

```
//replace the red pixels with yellow ones
int iWidth = bMap.getWidth();  
for (int i=0; i < bMap.getHeight(); i++)  
{  
    for(int j=0; j<bMap.getWidth(); j++)
    {
        iImageArray[(i*iWidth)+j] = 0xFF00FFFF; // actual value of yellow
    } 
}
```

Comment: thanks :) didnt realize that...... now if you want to print with some delay......suppose if add for(); above the iImageArray the whole UI is delayed......how to go about with this???

Comment: It's a bad idea to delay the GUI thread. You can start a new thread which takes its time to update the bitmap and then periodically tells the GUI thread to paint (postInvalidate) so that the user can see the action as it occurs.

Comment: ok i get the idea now :) but i am just a beginner here so if you can show me an example, it would be great :) thanks :)

Comment: You're asking me to write your program for you and that's not reasonable. You can find examples on SO of how to use threads in Android. One thing you do need to fix in your original code is to explicitly free the original bitmap (bMap.recycle) before you create a new bitmap from your iImageArray.

Comment: i think i have figured out the thread part. now i have commented in the post below. can you suggest me some ideas on how to move about with that???

Answer (score 1):

I also made a program that reads the RGB colors of every pixels from an image.
Here is my code to read:

```
int orgWidth = bmp.getWidth();
int orgHeight = bmp.getHeight();
//define the array size
int[] pixels = new int[orgWidth * orgHeight];

bmp.getPixels(pixels, 0, orgWidth, 0, 0, orgWidth, orgHeight);

for (int y = 0; y < orgHeight; y++){
    for (int x = 0; x < orgWidth; x++){
    }
}
```

This is how my array works.
I made a question for ranged pixel check last week, however I also fixed it by my self :)
[Optimize Color range check with nested for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225406/optimize-color-range-check-with-nested-for-loop)

**EDIT:**

Now I see, sorry.
at:  `iImageArray[j] = 0xFFFFFFFF;`
also add  `iImageArray[i] = 0xFFFFFFFF;`
then it should work

Comment: the answer is the same what i have asked in my question.......its printing pixel by pixel as how the for loops need to do!!!! rather it just printed a single line......and didnt change the rest of the image

Comment: You mean the for loops does work. But it is only printing 1 row of pixels?

Comment: i have a bitmap array which contains pixels of the bitmap image. now i want to print the pixels on screen pixel by pixel or say a block of pixels at a time, which the user also can see.....is there a way i can do this???? thanks in advance........and will canvas, paint, draw objects will come into picture????

Comment: I don't know that, I am not that skilled, just started with android java programming 2 weeks ago. BitBank has lot more rep, maybe he knows :)